# How to pass an array of values from Oracle Apex Page into Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ora-06550

I'm stuck with the passing Dates as an array parameters from the Oracle Apex page into package. Package contains one procedure with an array of type of dates. So what I want to do is to pass a simple dates into it from the Apex page, pl/sql block. Here is my code so far:

```
create or replace PACKAGE PK_NAME AS 

TYPE DATES_ARRAY_TYPE IS VARRAY(100) OF DATE;

PROCEDURE PASS_DATES (
      DATES DATES_ARRAY_TYPE
);

END PK_NAME;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY PK_NAME AS 

PROCEDURE PASS_DATES (
    DATES DATES_ARRAY_TYPE
) AS     
BEGIN    
for i in 1..DATES.count loop                 
   HTP.P(DATES(i));
end loop;
 END;
 END PASS_DATES;

 END PK_NAME;
```

Simple as that. And I call this procedure from the Apex page pl/sql block:

```
PK_NAME.PASS_DATES (
  DATES => '15-JAN-15', '16-JAN-15', '17-JAN-15'
);
```

However, it doesn't work, every time I'm trying to save it, it gives me an error:

> •ORA-06550: line 3, column 25: PLS-00312: a positional parameter association may not follow a named association ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

What is wrong with it or what have I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm

you must init constructor DATES_ARRAY_TYPE()
i think it must look like this

```
create TYPE DATES_ARRAY_TYPE IS VARRAY(100) OF DATE;

create or replace procedure test_case( p_dates DATES_ARRAY_TYPE) is 
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(p_dates(1));
end;

declare
 a DATES_ARRAY_TYPE;
begin
a := DATES_ARRAY_TYPE(sysdate, sysdate + 1,to_date('1.01.2016','dd.mm.yyyy'));
  test_case(a);
end;
```

also if you want to use TYPE in PACKAGE PK_NAME (not global) you must use object like PK_NAME.DATES_ARRAY_TYPE in your code.

**ok, lets go in your case:**
1. create package and body:
https://gyazo.com/789b875ce47852e859c395c2021f9cd4

```
create or replace PACKAGE PCK AS 
  -- your type in pck
  TYPE DATES_ARRAY_TYPE IS VARRAY(100) OF DATE;
  procedure test_case(p_dates DATES_ARRAY_TYPE);      
END PCK;

create or replace PACKAGE body PCK AS 
  procedure test_case(p_dates DATES_ARRAY_TYPE) IS
   BEGIN
    --here just raise second element in array for DEMO
    raise_application_error('-20000',p_dates(2) );
   END;
END PCK;
```

2.create page and button and after submit process:
https://gyazo.com/755f6e089db0a6a8ea058567d2b3384b

```
declare
  asd PCK.DATES_ARRAY_TYPE := PCK.DATES_ARRAY_TYPE('31-JUL-15', '01-AUG-15', '02-AUG-13', '03-AUG-13'); 
begin
  pck.test_case(asd);
end;
```

3. after button that submit page i get this: 
   https://gyazo.com/b894fc6b9b6dd28964ba2e6548244bc8

Comment: I've created one more region within the Apex page, with the code: "declare
   type array_t is varray(50) of date;
   array array_t := array_t('31-JUL-15', '01-AUG-15', '02-AUG-13', '03-AUG-13');
begin
   for i in 1..array.count loop
       htp.prn(array(i));
   end loop;
end;" It works fine, however, our requirements is to call package procedure from the Apex and pass array of dates, so this working example is not an option I'm afraid ... Any thoughts of how to embed it for our particular requirements ?! And thanks for the reply Анатолий, highly appreciated!

Comment: And when I trying to use PK_NAME.DATES_ARRAY_TYPE it gives me an error: "ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PLS-00221: 'DATES_ARRAY_TYPE' is not a procedure or is undefined ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored". And yes, I would like to use it from within the package. Thanks for the link, but I followed it when firstly created my package, simply tried to convert it to support my requirements. And requirements are, using the package and simply call procedure from the Apex Region pl/sql block and pass several dates as a parameters ...

Comment: hello my friend, i'm edit my answer to add some more examples and screenshots. see it, i hope this help you to solve problem. :)

Comment: Works as a charm, thanks a lot !!! My mistake was that I was calling procedure from the Apex without declaring, e.g. PK_NAME.PASS_DATES( .... etc. But if I declare first and then call, all works great. Thanks again !!!! You've made my day !! Большое человеческое Спасибо ! lol